# How to record max value of swap during period?

Tags: swap

I have some script that consumes a lot of swap memory.

How can I measure maximum swap load during script execution period ?

Is there any specific bash cli tool for my task ?

Comment: Well you can use some shell script that will check `swap` value in some interval of time and update the max value.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
trapexit() {
    echo -e "\nmax swap usage is $MAXUSAGE kb"
    exit 0
}
trap trapexit SIGINT
while true; do
    CURUSAGE=`free |awk '/Swap/{print $3}'`;
    if [[ $CURUSAGE -gt $MAXUSAGE ]]; then
            MAXUSAGE=$CURUSAGE;
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use shell script to find the maximum value of `swap` memory used.

```
#! /bin/bash
max=0
echo "$max" > max_value.txt
while true
do
#sleep 1
j=$(free -m | grep Swap| awk -F ' ' '{print $3}');
if [ "$max" -lt "$j" ]; then
max="$j";
echo "$max" > max_value.txt
fi
done
```

Initially I set `max=0` and wrote the output to some file `max_value.txt`.

```
j=$(free -m | grep Swap| awk -F ' ' '{print $3}');
```

This line will store the value of free `swap` memory available. And the if condition will compare this value to `max` value if it is greater then it will update the value of `max` and write it to `max_value.txt` file.

Now I am checking the free swap memory constantly so it can consume more `CPU` to run this script. However I have commented the line `sleep 1` you can use it to reduce the CPU consumption(I checked on my laptop there was reduction of `CPU` consumption from 10% to 1%), but it may happen that you will not get accurate result. If the variation in `used swap memory` is not sudden then you can get an approximate result.